# GoJS Adornment Placeholder is wrong in size

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have encountered something, what seems to me to be a bug of GoJS, although I am not sure if this behavior isn't by design.

When designing a context menu using the `go.Adornment` class, i tried to align two parts of the context menu each left and right of the node. This is also shown in the [GoJS context menu positioning example](http://gojs.net/latest/intro/contextMenus.html) on the official website.

Normally, zooming is disabled in the live preview, but pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-key and scrolling allows to make the nodes scale up without zooming the browser window.

If the context menu is called in this zoomed state, the go.Placeholder still has the size of the original node as if the zoom level had not changed.

Here some pictures of this issue:

[image: Original View]
[image: Zoomed]

I have to deal with the same issue in one of my applications, and used the example on the official page for convenience reasons.

Does anyone know a way to counteract this behavior, is there maybe even an official option to use which I just overlooked reading through the API? 
Or is it a bug? (do I have to wait for a fix to be published?)

Comment: What version of GoJS are you using?

Comment: In my application I am running v1.6.12 .
But the screenshots are from your website. Isn't it running the newest version?

Comment: I saw, on your website you are running v1.6.13 . Also in that version the issue still exists.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this bug.  We're working on a fix, which I hope to release very soon.

Comment: Would you expect the placeholder size to scale, or the entire adornment (the button size too) to scale?

Comment: @WalterNorthwoods Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: @SimonSarris Well, that depends, I'd say. In my case It would be best to have the adornment allways be the same size in relation to the view (so that only the placeholder would scale). However, the other solution you mentioned would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in, 1.6.14, which has just become the latest stable version.

http://gojs.net/latest/index.html

In the [changelog](http://gojs.net/latest/doc/changelog.html):

> If a Tooltip or Context Menu Adornment has a Placeholder, the placeholder's scale now changes with the Diagram.scale.